# Fastest way to load huge .dat into array

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

I have extensively searched in stackexchange a neat solution for loading a huge (~2GB) .dat file into a numpy array, but didn't find a proper solution. So far I managed to load it as a list in a really fast way (<1 min):

```
list=[]
f = open('myhugefile0')
for line in f:
    list.append(line)
f.close()
```

Using np.loadtxt freezes my computer and takes several minutes to load (~ 10 min). How can I open the file as an array without the allocating issue that seems to bottleneck np.loadtxt?

EDIT:

Input data is a float (200000,5181) array. One line example:

2.27069e-15 2.40985e-15 2.22525e-15 2.1138e-15 1.92038e-15 1.54218e-15 1.30739e-15 1.09205e-15 8.53416e-16 7.71566e-16 7.58353e-16 7.58362e-16 8.81664e-16 1.09204e-15 1.27305e-15 1.58008e-15

and so on

Thanks

Comment: do you have 64bit python? and how much ram do you have?

Comment: Yes, I have Canopy 64 bit Enthought distribution. My Ram is 8GB. I'm also using Spyder, I was also wondering if this could be a problem.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your input data?  At least a couple lines.

Comment: @cacosomoza have you tried `np.genfromtxt`?

Comment: Did you consider rewriting your data file to a data format that is more suited for relatively big data (fits or hdf5 or so), because for those things there are libraries that are specifically written to handle (relatively) big data

Comment: @SaulloCastro np.genfromtxt seems to be a much slower solution than the function posted by Bas Swinckles.

Comment: @usethedeathstar I'm not familiar with those formats. Could you point out a good reference? Thanks

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5 or https://pythonhosted.org/pyfits/users_guide/users_tutorial.html  pyfits is used a lot in the astronomy & astrophysics world, and hdf5 is another well-known dataformat specifically for big data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L628), it appears that `numpy.loadtxt` contains a lot of code to handle many different formats. In case you have a well defined input file, it is not too difficult to write your own function optimized for your particular file format. Something like this (untested):

```
def load_big_file(fname):
    '''only works for well-formed text file of space-separated doubles'''

    rows = []  # unknown number of lines, so use list
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
            rows.append(np.array(line, dtype = np.double))
    return np.vstack(rows)  # convert list of vectors to array
```

An alternative solution, if the number of rows and columns is known before, might be:

```
def load_known_size(fname, nrow, ncol)
    x = np.empty((nrow, ncol), dtype = np.double)
    with open(fname) as f:
        for irow, line in enumerate(f):
            for icol, s in enumerate(line.split()):
                x[irow, icol] = float(s)
    return x
```

In this way, you don't have to allocate all the intermediate lists.

**EDIT**: Seems that the second solution is a bit slower, the list comprehension is probably faster than the explicit for loop. Combining the two solutions, and using the trick that Numpy does implicit conversion from string to float (only discovered that just now), this might possibly be faster:

```
def load_known_size(fname, nrow, ncol)
    x = np.empty((nrow, ncol), dtype = np.double)
    with open(fname) as f:
        for irow, line in enumerate(f):
            x[irow, :] = line.split()
    return x
```

To get any further speedup, you would probably have to use some code written in C or Cython. I would be interested to know how much time these functions take to open your files.

Comment: Thanks Blas this is a great improvement. Just tried with a 1.9 Gb dat file (200000,864) floats. For unknown size: CPU times: user 1min 24s, sys: 5 s, total: 1min 29s
Wall time: 4min 14s
For known size:CPU times: user 1min 45s, sys: 2.52 s, total: 1min 47s
Wall time: 2min 12s
Pretty weird that the second function took more time

Comment: I will mark the answer as solution if anyone doesn't post a faster way to do it in a few days

Comment: One reason the second one might be slower is that the inner loop (`for icol, s ...`) is done in Python, while for the first function the inner loop is a list comprehension (`[float(s) for ...]`), which is implemented in C. You could try some hybrid solution, where you first convert to a list of floats using the list comprehension, and then set one complete row of the preallocated matrix `x` with `x[irow, :] = line`.

Comment: The order that you run the timing comparison can matter.  Your file system has a cache, so reading a file the second time can be faster than the first time, regardless of what you do with it.