# Speed up genfromtxt in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have several large text files (~ 1Gbyte each) with data, looking like this:

```
name name name name  
value - value value  
value value value value
value - - value
```

The text files are read via `numpy.genfromtxt`. My problem is that it is really slow. The problem is not the file input itself (I am mapping it into memory with `mmap` which is done in ~2 seconds, but the processing afterwards with `genfromtxt` is extremely slow. What can I do for speeding this up? I thought about parallelizing the progress by splitting the data into several smaller pieces, but for that I have to read the file first, process it completely, and afterwards run `genfromtxt` over each chunk. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Try `pandas.read_csv()` it's faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to load huge .dat into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482209/fastest-way-to-load-huge-dat-into-array)

Comment: @BasSwinckels: It is not a complete duplicate, because this question is more focused on speeding up `genfromtxt`, and not the reading itself...